# Key codes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question regarding the char codes for keyboards. I was reading this [article](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

This has a bunch of key codes.I want to check what key code to use when user presses the alt and down arrow.I have to create dropdowns like comboboxes which displays the list when user presses alt and down key.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try it for yourself -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PmVp6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyboard event has `event.altKey` to indicate whether alt was pressed.

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and exact answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find out any key code is to put `console.log(event.data.keyCode)` into your event function.
For example key code for "Alt + Down" is 4456488.